# Flutter http large file download and save on disk

Tags: flutter, http

I'm trying to save a large file from network to disk (160MB file). I'm saving the chunks as soon as they arrive but my saved file on disk is always corrupted and having variable size each time I re-run the script.

The reason I'm trying to save it as soon as a chunk has arrived is to save memory. I tried fetching the entire file and then save it, which caused my flutter to consume about 2GB of memory.

This is my code:

```
final request = http.Request('GET', uri);
final streamedResponse = await request.send();
File pathToSave = File('C:\\Downloads\\test.zip');

streamedResponse.stream.listen((value) async
{
    await pathToSave.writeAsBytes(value, mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend, flush: true);
})
```

I'm not sure but it seems the listen function doesn't wait for the previous callback to get finished and fires the next callback immediately and meddles with the previous file write.
Same script works fine with small files.

Flutter 3.0.5 (desktop)
Windows 11

Comment: `streamedResponse.stream.pipe(out)` where `IOSink out = File('.....').openWrite()`

Comment: Thank you. pipe works but since I wanted to also show download percentage, I used `out.add(value)` in the same function and it worked. The solution was to use `IOSink` which I didn't know about. You can post it as answer and I'll mark as solved.

Comment: you don't need `add` - just use `pipe` but before you call it call `map((e) { showPercentage(e); return e;})` - so it looks like `streamedResponse.stream.map(...).pipe(out)`

Comment: and it's even better if you do `streamedResponse.stream.map(_showDownloadProgress).pipe(out)` - where `_showDownloadProgress` is a method that shows the progress and simply returns it's input parameter without any changes

Comment: Alright yes that's even better. How would you do the error handling? With `try catch`? Because `listen()` comes with `onError`, `onDone` and `cancelOnError`.

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/handleError.html - also read about any other stream method - they can sometimes save you a lot of work ;-)

Comment: this can be also helpful: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams

Comment: Yes I'm on the right track. Thank you very much. If you like you can post an answer and I'll be happy to upvote.