# How to Write or save Large files in memory in flutter

Tags: flutter, out-of-memory, flutter-file

I'm currently facing an issue, where I'm trying to Save a large video file (586 Mb).
I'm able to download the entire file but, when I try to write this file to memory, I get an Error of “Out of memory”. It works for smaller video files like (80mb, 100 mb) but fails for the large files. I'm attaching the code snippet for reference.

```
Future download() async {
var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url!));
var response = httpClient.send(request).timeout(Duration(seconds: 3));

var chunks = <List<int>>[];
var downloaded = 0;
try{
  response.asStream().listen((http.StreamedResponse r) {
    if(r.statusCode==HttpStatus.ok){
      r.stream.listen((List<int> chunk) {
        // Display percentage of completion
        chunks.add(chunk);
        downloaded += chunk.length;
        downloadingCallBack(downloaded / r.contentLength! * 100,filesize(downloaded),filesize(r.contentLength));
      }, onDone: () async {
        // Display percentage of completion
        print('downloadPercentage: ${downloaded / r.contentLength! * 100}');
        // Save the file
        try{
          var file =  File('$dirPath/$fileName');
          //The Uint8List below throws the error "Out of memory and I'm not able to write the file to memory" 
         ***Error Here ==>*** final bytes = Uint8List(r.contentLength!); //Code fails here, (r.contentLength is 586900112 bytes)
          var offset = 0;
          for (var chunk in chunks) {
            bytes.setRange(offset, offset + chunk.length, chunk);
            offset += chunk.length;
          }
          await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
          downloadingDoneBack(true);
          return;
        }catch(fileException){
          rethrow;
        }finally{
          httpClient.close();
        }

      });
    }else{
      downloadingDoneBack(false);
    }

  });
}catch(e){
  downloadingDoneBack(false);
}finally{
  httpClient.close();
}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73153348/flutter-http-large-file-download-and-save-on-disk?noredirect=1#comment129198616_73153348

Comment: @pskink will i need to add streamedresponse.listen in the onDone Function?  It would be great if you can elaborate more

Comment: all you have to do is to use `pipe` method - you don't need any buffers, `listen` method, reading code etc

Comment: @pskink Unfortunately, I'm unable to follow what changes, Downloading and writing files is a new thing for me. I'm not sure Where the code will come, I would request you to share how the code of writing files will look like when I use pipe, maybe you can use the snippet of alex smith, from the link you shared

Comment: `if(r.statusCode==HttpStatus.ok) { r.stream.pipe(out); }` where `out = File('$dirPath/$fileName').openWrite()` - that's all

Comment: your welcome, and of course if you need to know when `pipe` method ends you have to `await` it (or use `.then(...)` on it's result)

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a large file, I think it would be better to download your file using [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) plugin which also supports notifications and background mode.

**Import and initialize flutter downloader**

```
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Plugin must be initialized before using
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
    debug: true // optional: set to false to disable printing logs to console (default: true)
    ignoreSsl: true // option: set to false to disable working with http links (default: false)
  );

  runApp(const MyApp())
}
```

**Create new download task**

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'your download link',
  savedDir: 'the path of directory where you want to save downloaded files',
  showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
);
```

**Handle isolates**

Important note: your UI is rendered in the main isolate, while download events come from a background isolate (in other words, codes in callback are run in the background isolate), so you have to handle the communication between two isolates. For example:

```
ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(_port.sendPort, 'downloader_send_port');
  _port.listen((dynamic data) {
    String id = data[0];
    DownloadTaskStatus status = data[1];
    int progress = data[2];
    setState((){ });
  });

  FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('downloader_send_port');
  super.dispose();
}

static void downloadCallback(String id, DownloadTaskStatus status, int progress) {
  final SendPort send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port');
  send.send([id, status, progress]);
}
```

**Load all download tasks**

```
final tasks = await FlutterDownloader.loadTasks();
```